# I can't send a POST request from view to Controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, request

I have this form shown below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("NewArticle", "News",FormMethod.Post, new { name = "createForm", onsubmit = "return validateFormNewPost()" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.adName, new { @class="form-control"})
   
    @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.tyepId, listType, "---Select Type---", new { @class = "form-control" })
    
    @Html.TextBox("imgPath", "", new { @class = "form-control", id = "imgPath" })
   
    @Html.TextAreaFor(p =>p.AdDescription,new { id = "editor" })

    <button class="btn btn-reset btn-dark" type="reset">Reset</button>
   
    <button class="btn-submit btn-primary btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult NewArticle()
{
    List<AdType> listType = typeModel.listForAdd();

    SelectList s = new SelectList(listType, "id", "AdType1");
    ViewBag.ListType = s;

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewArticle(Advertisement model,string imgPath)
{
    // my code

    return RedirectToAction("Category","News");
}
```

I'm trying to make a POST request by submit the form but it always send form data with a GET request. How can I fix it?

Comment: What does validateFormNewPost() ? Please attach the it  to your question

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending the POST? Are you using AJAX or JavaScript from your MVC page or are you trying to hit the endpoint with an external application like Telerik Fiddler or Postman?

You can not make a POST request directly from the browser using the URL, my assumption is that may be what you are doing.

Comment: Actually, what does your "validateFormNewPost()" actually do? I'm thinking this function may be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MethodNameinController", "Controller Name", FormMethod.Post))
{
  //form fields with submit button
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" id="create" />
}
```

And in Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MethodNameinController(Model model)
    {

    }
```